# Java - Send between clients

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming

I have two clients, and the server in between. I am trying to send information text between the clients.

It works for the first two seconds, but then it only receives information from the other client.

Here is the server code that handles the message sending:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 import javax.swing.*;

public class Server extends JFrame{

private JTextField userText;
private JTextArea chatWindow;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ObjectOutputStream output2;
private ObjectInputStream input2;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;
private Socket connection2;
private ServerSocket server2;
private String message;
private String message2;

  //constructor
public Server(){
  super("Server");
  userText = new JTextField();
  userText.setEditable(false);
  userText.addActionListener(
     new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
           try {
            sendMessage();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           userText.setText("");
        }
     }
  );
  add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  chatWindow = new JTextArea();
  add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
  setSize(300,150);
  setVisible(true);
 }

 //set up and run the server
  public void startRunning(){
  try{
     server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);
     server2 = new ServerSocket(6788,100);
     while(true){
        try{
           waitForConnection();
           waitForConnection2();
           setupStreams();
           whileChatting();
        }catch(EOFException eofException){
           showMessage("\n Server ended the connection! ");
        }finally{
           closeConnection();
        }
     }
  }catch(IOException ioException){
     ioException.printStackTrace();
  }
  }

  //wait for connection, then display connection information
 private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
  showMessage(" Waiting for someone to connect... \n");
  connection = server.accept();
  showMessage(" Now connected to client 1 \n");
  //
   }
  private void waitForConnection2() throws IOException{
   showMessage("Waiting for connection");
   connection2 = server2.accept();
   showMessage("Now connected to Client 2 \n");
     }

    //get stream to send and receive data
  private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
  output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
  output.flush();
  input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
  output2 = new ObjectOutputStream(connection2.getOutputStream());
  input2 = new ObjectInputStream(connection2.getInputStream());
  showMessage("\n Streams are now setup! \n");
   }

      //   during the chat conversation
   private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
    String message = " You are now connected! ";
     String message2 = "jiiii";


  try {
    sendMessage();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
  ableToType(true);
     //      while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END")){
    //         try{
   //            message = (String) input2.readObject();
   //            message2 = (String) input.readObject();
    //
   //            
   ////            showMessage("\n" + message);
   ////            showMessage("\n" + message2);
 //         }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
  //            showMessage("\n not valid");
   //         }
   //      }

    }

   //close streams and sockets after you are done chatting
    private void closeConnection(){
  showMessage("\n Closing connections... \n");
  ableToType(false);
  try{
     output2.close();
     input2.close();
     connection2.close();
     output.close();
     input.close();
     connection.close();
  }catch(IOException ioException){
     ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

   //send a message to client
   private void sendMessage() throws ClassNotFoundException{
   boolean msg1 = true;
   boolean msg2 = false;
      try{
          while(msg1 == true){
         message = (String)input.readObject();

             output2.writeObject("Phone" + message);
             output2.flush();
             msg1 = false;
             msg2 = true;
            }

          while(msg2 == true){
              message2 = (String)input2.readObject();
                 output.writeObject(message2);
                 output.flush();
                 msg1 = true;
          }








      }catch(IOException ioException){
         chatWindow.append("\n ERROR: DUDE I CANT SEND THAT MESSAGE");
      }
   }




  //updates chatWindow
  private void showMessage(final String text){
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
            chatWindow.append(text);
          }
        }
     );
  }

   //let the user type stuff into their box
    private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
     new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
           userText.setEditable(tof);
        }
     }
      );
   }

 }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it is the sendMessage method that is not working.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. You are making two ports, but instead you should be using one port and use threads so that the server can accept any number of connections.

Comment: But I only want two connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through the code of your sendMessage method.

```
private void sendMessage() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    boolean msg1 = true;
    boolean msg2 = false;
    try{
        while(msg1 == true){
            message = (String)input.readObject();
            output2.writeObject("Phone" + message);
            output2.flush();
            msg1 = false;
            msg2 = true;
        }

        while(msg2 == true){
            message2 = (String)input2.readObject();
            output.writeObject(message2);
            output.flush();
            msg1 = true;
        }
    } catch(IOException ioException){
        chatWindow.append("\n ERROR: DUDE I CANT SEND THAT MESSAGE");
    }
}
```

In the second while-loop, you don't put msg2 back to false, so it keeps running forever in that while-loop. That's why you stop receiving messages from the first client and only receive messages from the second client.

But when you correct this, the program will stop after 1 message from each client. To fix this, you need to put the 2 while-loops inside another while-loop, a while(true) loop for example, so they can alternate.

But that introduces yet another problem, you will not be able to stop your program while it is running. A possible solution could be that you introduce a local variable that is true, but changes to false when one of your clients enters a specific word ("quit" for example).

My example in code:

```
 private void sendMessage() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    boolean msg1 = true;
    boolean msg2 = false;
    boolean not-quit? = true; //Boolean to stop the program
    try{
        while(not-quit?) {
            while(msg1 == true){
                message = (String)input.readObject();
                if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("quit") {
                    not-quit? = false;
                }
                output2.writeObject("Phone" + message);
                output2.flush();
                msg1 = false;
                msg2 = true;
            }

            while(msg2 == true){
                message2 = (String)input2.readObject();
                if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("quit") {
                    not-quit? = false;
                }
                output.writeObject(message2);
                output.flush();
                msg1 = true;
                msg2 = false; //So it stops this while-loop
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException ioException){
        chatWindow.append("\n ERROR: DUDE I CANT SEND THAT MESSAGE");
    }
}
```

This style of Client-Server programming you are using is not so good. Another suggestion I can make is that you implement your Server with Threads, where each instance of communication with a Client is in a separate Thread, and you can let your Threads communicate via global variables in the Server. This is a much cleaner way of working!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It almost works, but each client only works for a limited amount of time, sometimes you can send three messeages on client2 and then you have to switch to client 1 and send some messages.

Comment: @theOGloc I don't really understand what you're trying to say, I think this method will strictly alternate between the two clients, so you receive only 1 message from a client and send only 1 message (the same one) to the other client. But this is not what you want?
I really strongly suggest that you look into implementing your server with Threads, this will make it easier and much cleaner!